# how to count how many person use the same id

Tags: mysql

I have this one table which is table staff. The column is `id_staff, no_staff` and `id_posting`. I would like to count how many staff using the same id_posting. Can anyone help me with the query?thanks.

Comment: Hint use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: `SELECT id_staff, COUNT(id_posting) FROM table_staff GROUP BY id_staff`

Comment: Why encourage posting poor quality questions? @MarkBaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
SELECT id_posting ,COUNT( `id_staff` ) as cnt_staff
FROM table_staff
GROUP BY id_posting
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have tried to make the query yourself?
This is quite basic

```
select count(id_staff), id_posting from staff where id_posting = ? group by id_posting
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select COUNT(*) AS ID_COUNT from YOUR_TABLE group by THE_ID_WHICH_IS_REPEATED
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp
check the tutorial for more info.